# Not able to fetch the video from the camera using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I not able to capture the video from the laptop video camera

I am using OpenCV- Python. I am trying to fetch the camera video but only showing single frame.

```
import cv2

# 1, -1, 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(0): #& OxFF == ord('q'): Error so commented
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Expecting the camera video but receiving only single frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supply `0` as the argument for `cv2.waitKey`, it wait until there is a keypress.  If you change `0` to `1` (or some other small number), the script works.

Out of interest, you can see the script 'works' even without changing the `0`.  If you repeatedly tap any key, the frame updates.

The thing with `0xFF` is that you have tried to use `O` (the letter) rather than `0` (the number), so python doesn't recognise it.

Full listing:

```
import cv2

# 1, -1, 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```